# AD LDS group auto completion

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, groups, ad-lds

i have problem with people picker with AD LDS with SharePoint 2013

The people picker does not search partial inputs (auto-completion) on the groups that i created in the AD LDS.
However, it works fine on users.

Does anyone know if is a SharePoint Limitation or if it is something wrong in my configuration:

the weg.config of my IIS webapp is described hereafter :

**membership provider :**

```
<providers>
    <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
<add name="membershipXXX" 
    type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    server="**********************" 
    port="*****" 
    useSSL="true" 
    connectionUsername="CN=LDS_Bind,CN=Services,CN=***,DC=***,DC=***" 
    connectionPassword="***" 
    useDNAttribute="true" 
    userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
    userNameAttribute="cn" 
    userContainer="CN=Users,CN=***,DC=***,DC=***" 
    userObjectClass="user" 
    userFilter="(ObjectClass=user)" 
    scope="Subtree" 
    otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
</providers>
```

**RoleManager :**

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="rolemanagerXXX" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    server="**********************" 
    port="*****" 
    useSSL="true" 
    connectionUsername="CN=LDS_Bind,CN=Services,CN=***,DC=***,DC=***" 
    connectionPassword="**********" 
    enableSearchMethods="true" groupContainer="CN=Users,CN=***,DC=***,DC=***" 
    groupNameAttribute="cn" 
    groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="cn" 
    groupMemberAttribute="member" 
    userNameAttribute="cn" 
    dnAttribute="distinguishedName" 
    useUserDNAttribute="true" 
    scope="Subtree" 
    userFilter="&amp;(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)" 
    groupFilter="&amp;(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=group)" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**PeoplePicker :**

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />
  <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
  <add key="rolemanagerXXX" value="*" />
  <add key="membershipXXX" value="*" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Thanks for your help !!!